# IE 11 Keep freezing when going to some sites

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

When i try to visit some websites with Internet Explorer 11 it keeps freezing.

```
http://techcrunch.com/gallery/15-hidden-features-tucked-away-in-ios-9/
dailymail.co.uk
```

When you're browsing it eventually freeze and you can't do anything until you force the browser to close.

I've tried some sites with Mozilla Firefox and other browser and they work without any problems.

I'm using

```
Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bits
Internet Explorer 11
```

My PC haves the lastest Updates Installed.

I've tried this:

- Internet Explorer without addon (Still same problems)
- Internet Explorer with Disabled Complements (Still same problem)
- Reset IE
- Tick Use Software Rendering
- Reset all Zones to Default level

Comment: I have update the question

Comment: Have you tried compatibility view for those sites?

Comment: it was working fine since last 2 weeks, and nothing has been change since then. We have over 4000 users

Comment: Do an IE reset, Internet Options>Advanced tab>Reset button.

Comment: Already try this.

Comment: @maj any luck? Having similar issues. Wonder if a recent Windows update has caused it.

Comment: I try everything but same problem. You can try these things which does help.

1. Update flash player
2. Remove IE and then re-install agan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by uninstalling the update KB4022168.("Control Panel > Programs (or Programs & Features) > In top of left column select 'View Installed Updates'")

Instructions can be found here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/internet-explorer-11-mshtmldll-keeps-crashing-when/19a1819e-27d2-4d01-ae05-d6a9365125e4?auth=1

Answer (score 1):

Browser problems are almost always caused by compatibility issues between the core browser and the add-ons, extensions, toolbars you've installed or the custom settings you've tweaked your browser with.

1.Clear Internet Explorer Cache, run your antivirus software to check for malware infections. Run sfc /scannow and at the end, reboot if asked for. This will replace corrupted system files if any. Finally, Open IE, click Tools > Internet options > Security > Reset all Zones to Default level, and see if it helps.

2.In Internet Options, go to Advanced Tab and click on Reset tab. Restart IE. The Reset Internet Explorer option deletes all temporary files, disables any add-ons, plug-ins, toolbars and resets all changed settings to default. Although this is a quick-fix, you will have to re-install the add-ons.

3.Use Software Rendering instead of GPU Rendering and see if stops the crashes. You will find the setting under Internet Options > Advanced tab.

4.Click the Advanced tab; then click Reset.In the Reset Internet Explorer Settings dialog box, leave the “Delete personal settings” box unchecked to preserve items such as stored website passwords. Click Reset to start the process, when Internet Explorer finishes restoring its default settings, click Close and then click OK to exit the Reset process. Restart your PC.

I hope something helps you.

Comment: I have tried all of your points but still same problem.

Comment: Make a few changes in the Registry. Do back up your registry and create a System Restore Point, before making any changes.

Run regedit and navigate to the following key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
Right-click in the right page and select New.
Create a New DWORD value called “MaxConnectionsPerServer”
Double-click “MaxConnectionsPerServer” and give the value as “10”
Create another new DWORD with the name “MaxConnectionsPer1_0Server”
Double-click it and give the value as “10”.
Save and Exit from the registry.
Restart Windows.

Comment: Additionally also see if the following registry subkey is enabled:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\UseCoInstall
If it is absent, no issues. But if it is present and of its DWORD value is set at 1, change this value to 0, Click OK and Exit.

Comment: I just added the keys and again still same problem

Comment: This key doesnt existed UseCoInstall

Answer (score 0):

[Compatability View Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCroz.png)

[Add site to Compatability View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEAuD.png)

add website

- Internet options, tab security, Trusted sites, sites add website
  [Add website to trusted sites](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8ckS.png)